# Meaning of bed-related terms

Tags: word-request, nouns

I am not an English speaker, but I want to buy everything that has to be on a bed and I want to use Amazon.

Bedspreads, blankets, bed-throws, duvet covers, fitted sheets, flat sheets, quilts - those are hard to understand especially when in pictures they all look like a piece of cloth...

What do I need?

1. The bottom layer has to be simply a rectangular piece of clothing which has dimensions similar to the ones of bed in question. So a flat sheet?
2. Pillows and pillow cases. This one is pretty clear.
3. Thing which keeps people warm. That sure looks like a duvet. Maybe quilt is also used for that purpose, difference being that it's not filled with goose feathers?
4. Clothing which is "wrapped" around the item #3. Probably a duvet cover... What about a quiltset? I'm not sure whether it usually means pillow cases + item #3 or pillow cases + item #1.
5. Clothing which lays on top of everything mainly for aesthetics (during the day for example). Bed-throw?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, working from the bottom layer up:

**Ruffle Sheet**:  Sits between the base and mattress components of an ensemble bed for decorative/ornamental purposes.  (Optional.)

**Electric blanket**: sits on top of the mattress and is connected to an electrical cable which allows the bed to be pre-warmed.  In the US, Electric Blankets are known as Electric Mattress Pads.  (Non-optional in cold areas, especially if there are no other forms of heating available - eg hot-water bottles.)

**Mattress protector**:  Flat (ie, non-fitted) but usually padded sheet with elastic added to corner edges. Goes over mattress to protect it and elastic slips under corners of mattress to keep it in place.  (Optional.)

**Bottom sheet**:  Can be a flat sheet, but is usually a 'fitted sheet'.  Fitted sheets are elasticated in the corners to make it easier to a) make the bed and b) keep the sheet positioned correctly overnight.

**Top sheet**:  Flat sheet.  (Generally, bodies sleep between bottom and top sheets.)

**Electric Overblanket**:  Largely a US phenomenon, these are similar to Electric Blankets/Mattress Pads except they are placed above the top sheet.  In the US, they are called simply 'electric blankets'.  This can cause some confusion.

[**Blankets** | **Duvet/Doona/Comforter/Continental Quilt** ]
Blankets: Generally thick (often wooly) rectangles that you add more of depending on how cold it is.

Duvets: (doonas in Australian) are bags with an insulating material (usually down/feathers, but also cotton and synthetics) inside.  Usually (in contrast to blankets) only one duvet is worn on a bed.  A duvet is usually wrapped in a duvet-cover which serves a similar purpose as pillow-cases do for pillows.  In the US, the term is *comforter*, and confusion can arise as 'duvet' is sometimes used to refer to the cover/case specifically, unlike in Europe where it is the bag itself, or the bag+case.

**Quilt**:  Top covering that serves a dual purpose as decoration and an extra blanket (depending on material, thickness etc).  Not as commonly used with duvets as with blankets.

Quiltset isn't a single word (except perhaps in a marketing context), but quilt-set usually refers to a quilt / duvet cover that matches with pillowcases and possibly a ruffle sheet to create a coordinated look for the bedroom.  The contents of the set (ie, whether you get two or four pillowcases, or whether a ruffle sheet is included) are dependent on the vendor (and price).

As snailplane has commented, for a number of reasons - different regions, different types of beds (eg, mattress protectors make no sense on a waterbed), marketing, etc - there is no hard and fast rule for all these names.  However if you take this list while google-shopping, you should know what you want to order when you hit Amazon's checkout.

Comment: What you're calling an electric blanket isn't one. An electric blanket is still a blanket, i.e. it goes above the flat sheet (and the user of the bed). What you seem to be describing is an electric mattress pad.

Comment: @Martha: I think somehow, those things are nearly always called electric blankets anyway, despite the technical incorrectness. I remember being confused by this as a child.

Comment: It seems to be a difference between the US and UK, at least in Wikipedia.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_blanket  All I can say is in the US I have only heard of an electric blanket over the flat sheet.

Comment: Edited to include Electric (Over)blankets.  (Doesn't the US know that heat rises?)

Comment: @mcalex: we're perfectly aware that heat rises; that's why there are heated mattress pads. We're also aware that the term "blanket" refers to a covering that goes *over* the occupant of a bed. :)

Comment: touché. So the US names them correctly, ROTW uses them correctly?    :-)

Comment: Yes, blankets go over things. As far as I'm concerned, over the mattress! Under the sheet and under the person. I've never experienced a heated blanket on top of me... (Brit in NZ). Here the shops sell a 'sheet set' which is a flat (or sometimes fitted) undersheet, another flat oversheet, and a pillow case. OR a 'Duvet set' which is a duvet cover and a pillow case, sometimes also with a flat or fitted undersheet. There will be one or two pillow cases included depending on bed size.